# Remove A Cell If It's Column Doesn't Have A Header Section

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to check if a cell's column has a `thead` above it in a table? I want to `.remove('td')` if it's not in a column with a `thead`.

**Visual:**

[image]

*stating the obvious but to reiterate with illustration, since the last cell doesn't have a header above it I want it to be deleted from the DOM*

```css
table {border: 1px solid;}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 75px;
}
th {height: 40px;}
td {height: 75px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>   <!-- SHOULD BE REMOVED -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/7dvt9tam/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the total colspan values (= the max cells allowed / row)
Than using the [`:gt()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/), get rid of all the exceeding TD elements

```js
$("table").each(function(){
  var maxCell = 0;
  $(this).find("th").prop("colspan", function(i,v){
    maxCell += v;
  });
  $(this).find("td:gt("+(maxCell-1)+")").remove();
});
```

```css
table {border: 1px solid;}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 75px;
}
th {height: 40px;}
td {height: 75px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above works even if you don't define the `colspan` attr:

```
  <th>Header</th>
  <th colspan="2">Header</th>
```

***[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/hizihuh/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I may dynamically add cells as well! Should I just change *the first* instance of `.find` to `.on` to make this work?

Comment: @CSSApprentice i have no idea how you're adding those cells and where

Comment: @CSSApprentice if you're adding cells dynammically how you're than adding TH? Please make your thoughts clear!

Comment: Yes, very sorry :/ You've already answer my first question, so I'll select your answer! Just curious, if I changed the colspan in the DOM, could I make this automatically check by using `.on` instead of `.find`. *And you don't have to update your answer for this question unless you would like to*

Comment: @CSSApprentice IF you're adding TH dynamically, than inside the function that appends your TH elements you should perform the exact same function from example.

Comment: Note for future viewers, changing `$(this).find("td:gt("+(maxCell-1)+")").remove();` to `$('tr').find("td:gt("+(maxCell-1)+")").remove();` will prevent it from removing table rows if you add more. jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/7dvt9tam/2/